# Nested if-else loops in R

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame named "crimes" which contains a "pre_rate" column that denotes the crime rate before a certain law is implemented. I would like to put each rate in a "rate_category" column using a nested if-else loop. I have the following code:

```
crimes$rate_category = 
  with(crimes, ifelse(pre_rate > 0.26 && pre_rate < 0.87, 1,
    ifelse(pre_rate > 1.04 && pre_rate < 1.94, 2, 
      ifelse(pre_rate > 2.03 && pre_rate < 2.96, 3, 
        ifelse(pre_rate > 3.10 && pre_rate < 3.82, 4, 
          ifelse(pre_rate > 4.20 && pre_rate < 11.00, 5, "NA"))))))
crimes
```

and here's a reproducible example:

```
pre_rate = c(0.27, 1.91, 2.81, 3.21, 4.80) 
crimes = data.frame(pre_rate)   
crimes
```

However, when I run the loop with my original data frame, all levels in the "rate_category" column is incorrectly set to 1. What seems to be the problem with the loop above?

Comment: Be careful about using `&&`: it only compares the first element of the vectors. `&` does element-wise comparisons, which is probably what you wanted.

Comment: Also I think having a character `"NA"` in your final `ifelse` will mess up the column by converting it to character. Just use `NA`, no quotes.

Comment: Is it really your goal to have gaps? For example do you want a pre-rate of 2 to be NA?

Comment: @Hugh all the rates are 8 decimals long, so I'm just rounding them to the hundredths place. There will be gaps but the won't contain any relevant data.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of nesting ifelse statements might I recommend using `case_when`. It is a bit easier to read/follow. But as @Marius mentioned your problem is the `&&` instead of using `&`.

```
library(tidyverse)
crimes <- data.frame(pre_rate = c(0.27, 1.91, 2.81, 3.21, 4.80))

crimes %>% 
  mutate(rate_category = case_when(pre_rate > 0.26 & pre_rate < 0.87 ~ 1,
                                   pre_rate > 1.04 & pre_rate < 1.94 ~ 2,
                                   pre_rate > 2.03 & pre_rate < 2.96 ~ 3,
                                   pre_rate > 3.10 & pre_rate < 3.82 ~ 4,
                                   pre_rate > 4.20 & pre_rate < 11.00 ~ 5))
```

Comment: between() might be useful here.

Comment: @Hugh According to the help page, `?dplyr::between` *is a shortcut for `x >= left & x <= right`* but the OP is asking for *strict* inequalities. The `data.table` implementation of `between()` has a parameter to enforce strict inequalities, e.g., `data.table::between(x, lower, upper, incbounds = FALSE)`.

Comment: Correct. From the OP's comment, however, it seems probable that that distinction doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

Why not define your lower bounds and upper bounds in two vectors then rely on indexing? Using this method, there is no need to write `pre_rate > num1 & pre_rate < num2` multiple times.

```
lowB <- c(0.26, 1.04, 2.03, 3.10, 4.2)
uppB <- c(0.87, 1.94, 2.96, 3.82, 11)

myCategory <- 1:5 ## this can be whatever categories you'd like

crimes$rate_category <- with(crimes, myCategory[pre_rate > lowB & pre_rate < uppB])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of multiple nested `ifelse()`, a *non-equi join* and *update on join* can be used

```
# OP's sample data set with one out-of-bounds value appended
crimes = data.frame(pre_rate = c(0.27, 1.91, 2.81, 3.21, 4.80, 1.0))   

library(data.table)
# specify categories, lower, and upper bounds
bounds <- data.table(
  cat = 1:5,
  lower = c(0.26, 1.04, 2.03, 3.10, 4.2),
  upper = c(0.87, 1.94, 2.96, 3.82, 11)
)
# non-equi join and update on join
setDT(crimes)[bounds, on = .(pre_rate > lower, pre_rate < upper), rate_category := cat][]
```

> ```
>    pre_rate rate_category
> 1:     0.27             1
> 2:     1.91             2
> 3:     2.81             3
> 4:     3.21             4
> 5:     4.80             5
> 6:     1.00            NA
> ```

Note that `pre-rate` values which are outside of any of the given intervals do get a `NA` `rate_category` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You may use algebraic approach to solve your problem, it should be faster than your ifelse:

```
pre_rate = c(0.27, 1.91, 2.81, 3.21, 4.80) 
crimes = data.frame(pre_rate)   
crimes$rate = (pre_rate > 0.26 & pre_rate < 0.87)*1 + 
  (pre_rate > 1.04 & pre_rate < 1.94)* 2 + 
  (pre_rate > 2.03 & pre_rate < 2.96)* 3 + 
  (pre_rate > 3.10 & pre_rate < 3.82)* 4 + 
  (pre_rate > 4.20 & pre_rate < 11.00)* 5
```

The idea here is to just get true or false values from expression, then it is getting multiplied by the number for which you see that as a category. The only difference would be that you won't be getting NAs here for non match instead you will get a zero, which you can off course change it. Also to add, Use "&" in cases where you want to vectorize (element by element match) your outcome as mentioned in the comments.

**Output:**

```
#> crimes
# pre_rate rate
#1     0.27    1
#2     1.91    2
#3     2.81    3
#4     3.21    4
#5     4.80    5
```

Comment: You could also only include the `<` relationships and omit the coefficients for a strictly increasing encoding.

Answer (score 0):

If your data does not contain gaps, and you just want an index, you can use `.bincode`:

```
crimes$rate_category <- .bincode(crimes$pre_rate,
                                 breaks = c(-Inf, 1, 2, 3, 4, Inf))
```

If you want specific values for each interval, you can use a rolling join via the `data.table` package:

```
library(magrittr)
library(data.table)

rate_category_by_pre_rate <- 
  data.table(rate_category = c("foo", "bar", "foobar", "baz", "foobie"),
             pre_rate = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 11)) %>%
  setkey(pre_rate)

crimes %>%
  as.data.table %>%
  setkey(pre_rate) %>%
  rate_category_by_pre_rate[., roll = -Inf]

#>    rate_category pre_rate
#> 1:           foo     0.27
#> 2:           bar     1.91
#> 3:        foobar     2.81
#> 4:           baz     3.21
#> 5:        foobie     4.80
```

However, in your case, you may only need `ceiling` (*i.e.* round-up the value of `pre_rate` and cap it at 5:

```
crimes$rate_category <- pmin(ceiling(crimes$pre_rate), 5)

#>   pre_rate rate_category
#> 1     0.27             1
#> 2     1.91             2
#> 3     2.81             3
#> 4     3.21             4
#> 5     4.80             5
```